# How do I get the App Store country of an app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need a way to get the country code of an app I'm making in Xamarin (both Android and iOS). Language is not enough because many people (like me) use English as the language on their phones.

I've already tried the following:

-RegionInfo.CurrentRegion (returns language set in settings)

-CultureInfo.CurrentCulture (returns language set in settings)

-NSLocale Class (only works on iOS)

Comment: You could check the suggestion provided by PhilipOchu. It is a new option to get the country.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33354/is-it-possible-to-get-the-users-more-accurately-the-devices-or-sims-home-country

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency service:

```
Shared:
    public interface IRegionCulture
    {
        CultureInfo GetRegionCulture();
    }

Android:
    public CultureInfo GetRegionCulture()
    {
        return new CultureInfo(Java.Util.Locale.Default.ToString());
    }

iOS:
    public CultureInfo GetRegionCulture()
    {
        var code = NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode;
        var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.EndsWith("-" + code, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        return culture;
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction